# Rust async-await: check if any future in a list resolves to true concurrently?

Tags: concurrency, rust, async-await

I'm trying to run a list of futures concurrently (instead of in sequence) in Rust async-await (being stabilized soon), until any of them resolves to `true`.

Imagine having a `Vec<File>`, and a future to run for each file yielding a `bool` (may be unordered). Here would be a simple sequenced implementation.

```rust
async fn my_function(files: Vec<File>) -> bool {
    // Run the future on each file, return early if we received true
    for file in files {
        if long_future(file).await {
            return true;
        }
    }

    false
}

async fn long_future(file: File) -> bool {
    // Some long-running task here...
}
```

This works, but I'd like to run a few of these futures concurrently to speed up the process. I came across [`buffer_unordered()`](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.19/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffer_unordered) (on `Stream`), but couldn't figure out how to implement this.

As I understand it, something like [`join`](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.19/futures/?search=Join) can be used as well to run futures concurrently, given that you gave a multithreaded pool. But I don't see how that could efficiently be used here.

I attempted something like this, but couldn't get it to work:

```rust
let any_true = futures::stream::iter(files)
    .buffer_unordered(4) // Run up to 4 concurrently
    .map(|file| long_future(file).await)
    .filter(|stop| stop) // Only propagate true values
    .next() // Return early on first true
    .is_some();
```

Along with that, I'm looking for something like [`any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) as used in iterators, to replace the if-statement or the `filter().next().is_some()` combination.

How would I go about this?

Comment: check out [futures::select!](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/06_multiple_futures/03_select.html)

Comment: I think the problem with the `select` macro is that you need branches for every future that might complete. Maybe [futures::future::select_ok](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.19/futures/future/fn.select_ok.html) is better?

Comment: Thanks! I thought `select` would need to cover and yield all branches first, but with `select_ok` apparently not, and it allows an early return, so that is perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you should be able to use `select_ok`, as mentioned by Some Guy. An example, in which I've replaced the files with a bunch of `u32` for illustration:

```rust
use futures::future::FutureExt;

async fn long_future(file: u32) -> bool {
    true
}

async fn handle_file(file: u32) -> Result<(), ()> {
    let should_stop = long_future(file).await;
    // Would be better if there were something more descriptive here
    if should_stop {
        Ok(())
    } else {
        Err(())
    }
}

async fn tims_answer(files: Vec<u32>) -> bool {
    let waits = files.into_iter().map(|f| handle_file(f).boxed());

    let any_true = futures::future::select_ok(waits).await.is_ok();

    any_true
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'd like to explicitly note that [`boxed()`](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.19/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.boxed) is used to [`Pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html) the value, as required by `select_ok`.